# Почему через ссылку на сайт в GitHub не отображаются картинки?

Tags: html, github, frontend

Подскажите пожалуйста, если хостить на GitHub свой сайт, то несколько картинок которые размещены на сайте через тег img не отображаются, в чем может быть проблема? Как это исправить?

Comment: Измените путь к фото. Учитывайте, что локально он выглядит иначе нежели на GitHub. Я когда только начал пользоваться GitHub, слету столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой и вот таким образом ее успешно решил.

Comment: я только что на github создал директорию img и закачал туда фото и открыл его в index.html на рабочем столе ... фото отобразилось в браузере ...

Comment: @Vlad Spirin Другой сайт, в котором путь к фото указан аналогично, отображает картинки. Да и на этом же сайте, в котором такая проблема, другие картинки отображаются и только несколько нет...